# The size of commuting subset of a Group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group such that if $H$ is a subset of $G\setminus Z(G)$ and any two element of $H$ commute, then $H$ is finite. Is it true that the set of all the sizes of such $H$ has a maximum element? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A little observation: any element $x \in G \setminus Z(G)$ must have finite order. Suppose not. Note $H = \langle x \rangle \setminus Z(G)$ has pairwise commuting elements  and is therefore finite. In particular, we have $x^n , x^{n+1} \in Z(G)$ for large enough $n$. But then, $x \in Z(G)$, contrary to assumption.

Comment: Maximal elements exist among $H$ by Zorn's lemma, but of course this is not enough to conclude that the set of sizes of such $H$ contains a maximum element. Also, any maximal element is $A - Z(G)$ where $A$ is an abelian subgroup of $G$ and $Z(G) \leq A$. So it suffices to consider abelian subgroups of $G$ that contain $Z(G)$. In a counterexample, $A - Z(G)$ would be finite for any abelian subgroup $A$ containing $Z(G)$ and $A - Z(G)$ could be arbitrarily large.

Comment: Your question is a dual of a famous question of Erdos : If $G$ is a group such that any subset $H$ consisting of mutually non commuting elements is finite, Then are they boundedly finite?, the answer was given in the afirmative by B. H. Neumann (1976) 'A   problem   of   Paul   Erdos  on   groups'  J .Austral. Math. Soc.

Comment: Note also (in the sprit of Neumann), that you can reforlmulate your question as Graph theoretic one.  Consider the elements of $G\Z(G)$ as vertices, and connect to vertices $x$ and $y$ by an edge if they commute;  your condition is equivalent to that every complete subgraph is finite.  I will not be surprised if an answer follows from a pure graph theoretic argument.

Comment: I am a little confused by this question - do you mean "H is a finite set of pairwise commuting, non-central elements". Can you not just take $C_2\ast C_3\ast C_4\ast\ldots$? What am I missing?

Comment: @user1729 A free product has cyclic subgroups of infinite order that do not intersect $Z(G)$, so it does not satisfy the hypothesis.

Comment: @user1729 $H$ is a finite set of pairwise commuting non-central elements only.

Comment: @DerekHolt So the question asks if there always exists a bound on the finite commuting sets? Okay, I think I have it (so, for example, a Tarski monster would not be a counter-example because the only finite sets have order bounded by the ambient prime $p$).

Comment: Actually...would Golod-Shafarevich's example not work? They give a torsion group with elements of unbounded order...

Comment: @user1729 Please can you give a link, or name of a paper or name of a book where i can find "Golod-shafarevich example".

Comment: @deibor The Golod-Sharafrevich example was the first finitely-generated infinite group where every element has finite order. It just so happened that the order of every element was infinite. Look up the Burnside problem (I don't think this group answers your question though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try.

First, the center should be finite, otherwise the coset of any non-central element $xZ(G)$ is an infinite abelian subset in $G-Z(G)$.

As any subset with pairwise commuting elements generates an abelian subgroup, and conversely the elements of any abelian subgroup are pairwise commuting, we are actually asking about a group in which every abelian subgroup is finite (this is caused by the finiteness of the center), with no bound on the order of these subgroups.

Such a question is already asked in MathOverflow ( see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/80998/groups-with-no-bounds-on-the-size-of-abelian-subgroups-without-infinite-ones) , and such a group is already constructed in Olshanskii's book "The Geometry of defining relations in groups".

I reproduce the answer here : There exists a countable $2$-generated simple group $G$, that contains a copy of any cyclic group of odd order, moreover every proper subgroup of $G$ is either cyclic (of order dividing some integer $n$) or a conjugate to one of our embedded copies of the cyclic groups.